# Pair of torsors and divisors and Galois cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, galois-cohomology

Let $E/\Bbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve.
$H^1(G_{\Bbb{Q}},E[2])$ is bijection with the set of pair of torsors and divisor of degree $2$. Let call the latter set $WCD(E/\Bbb{Q})$.

I tried to construct a bijection between them.

Is the following correct ? I'm having difficulty showing its well-definedness, so I my try is not on the right track.

Take $[C,[D]]\in WCD(E/\Bbb{Q})$ where $C$ is a curve and $[D]$ is a divisor class.
Let fix an $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$-isomorphism $f: E\cong C$ **such that $[n]\circ f$ is defined over $\Bbb{Q}$**. Then $\sigma \mapsto \sigma(f)-f$ where $\sigma(f)$ is action where $\sigma$ acts on its coefficients.

Then, $n\circ (\sigma(f)-f)=0$ and we can define cockle from $[C,[D]]$.

But how can we take $f$ such that $f: E\cong C$ **such that $[n]\circ f$ is defined over $\Bbb{Q}$**? Or am I go on a wrong track, how can I correctly define a cocycle from torsor divisor pair $[C,[D]]$ ?

Comment: I highly recommend [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606580), which gives multiple parameterisations for $H^1(G_K, E[n])$, including your one.